# How to detect "no carrier" SIM card mode?

Tags: android, sim-card

How do I detect when the GSM signal strength is low and the cellular network is lost?
What about dual SIM devices?

Answer (score 3):

> Android: how to detect “no carrier” SIM card mode ?

The [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) class is designed to serve this purpose. When using it, you can get callbacks when the GSM signal bound to your current provider is changing.

Make sure you have the following `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` set in your manifest file.

Next, you'll need to invoke the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and bind your `PhoneStateListener` to it :

```
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
telManager.listen(this.phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

You can implement your `PhoneStateListener` as such :

```
private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        Log.d("onSignalStrengthsChanged", "The new singal strength is " 
                + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
    }

};
```

GSM signal strengths values are defined in `TS 27.007 8.5`. Basically a value of 0 is *low*, a value of 31 is *good*, and a value of 99 means *not known or not detectable*. Valid values are (0-31, 99) as stated in the [Android Developers manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength%28%29).

The above covers GSM signals, so if you are only interested in GSM signals, stick to my previous example. If you might be interested in stating whether a *data network* is available or not due to a lack of signal strength, you can also get other signal values for all the available data networks :

- [SignalStrength.getCdmaDbm()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getCdmaDbm%28%29) returns the RSSI value in dBm for CDMA networks.
- [SignalStrength.getEvdoDbm()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getEvdoDbm%28%29) returns the RSSI value in dBm for Evdo networks.

You can know what is the type of the current data network by calling the [`TelephonyManager.getNetworkType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType%28%29) method.

> What about dual SIM devices ?

I don't know, never worked on them. However I don't see why the above may not be applicable to multi-SIM devices. It should be working as such.

Comment: Thanks much !
Seems, actually need to check onServiceStateChanged waiting for "1" that is "OUT_OF_SERVICE".
Or is lowest signal more correct state ? Never used...

Comment: You can watch for a `STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE` event in a onServiceStateChanged of course. The onSignalStrengthsChanged may just give you the opportunity to know in a more detailed manner what the state of the signal is. This can help you to define the level at which the signal strength is becoming acceptable or unacceptable for your application.